# Asserting that both pointers point to NULL is not happening after delete()

Tags: c++, struct, assert

Given this little piece of code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;


struct Foo
{
    // something
};


int main()
{

    Foo *p1 = new Foo;
    Foo * p2 = p1;
    assert(NULL != p1);
    delete p1;
    p1 = NULL;

    assert(NULL != p2);
    delete p2;

    cout << "everything is cool!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I delete `p1` , the second assert (`assert(NULL != p2);`) is not failing , why ?

The output : `everything is cool!`

Then why the assert of `p2` is not failing ?

Comment: Because p2 is still set to whatever address p1 had. It does not get the value of p1 after that changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Watch the stars, in particular.

   ```
   int i;

   int *p1 = &i;
   assert(p1 != NULL);

   int *p2 = p1;
   assert(p2 != NULL);

   *p1 = 10;
   assert(i == 10);
   assert(*p2 == 10);

   p1 = NULL; // does not affect the object p1 was pointing at

   assert(i == 10);
   assert(*p2 == 10);
   assert(p2 != NULL); // (which we already know, if the previous assert didn't crash)
   ```
2. You're right to suspect that everything is not cool.  The program invokes the delete operator twice on the same object (a "double free" error), which will tend to corrupt the heap.  If the program continued, you would see undefined behavior at some point.  Having undefined behavior rather defeats the point of writing a computer program.  If you want to see errors like this immediately and unambiguously, run it under valgrind's memcheck or [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows).

Answer (score 4):

> When I delete p1 , the second assert (assert(NULL != p2);) is not
>   failing , why ?

Deleting `p1` or assigning to it has no effect on `p2` itself. After you delete `p1`, `p2` still points to that address, i.e. to a defunct object. It becomes a so-called dangling pointer. Of course, accessing it or deleting it (which you're doing) is undefined behavior.

Comment: "illegal" should be "undefined behavior"

Comment: @tenfour I was just getting tired of "undefined behavior", thought I'd try something different.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest and most confusing-to-beginners misnomer in C++ is the term "deleting a pointer". This has undoubtedly originated from the fact that a `delete` expression takes a *pointer* as its argument:

```
T * p = new T;  // #1
delete p;       // #2
```

However, what's really going on is that line #1 creates a new, dynamic, *unnamed* object. Think about this again: There is *no* variable whose value is the object create in line #1. The object is really out of reach, as indeed it does not live in any scope. All we have is a *pointer* to it.

To end the lifetime of a dynamic variable, we have to use a `delete` expression. But since we already know that we can only ever really have a *pointer* the object, not the object itself*, the expression con­veni­ent­ly accepts a *pointer* to the object we're deleting.

So really we should say that in line #2 "we are deleting the object `*p` by giving a pointer to it to the `delete` expression" (namely `&*p == p`).

*The pointer itself is entirely unaffected by the `delete` call.*

<sub>*) Yes, we could also have a *reference* variable, like `T & r = *new T;`, but that would be insane.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`delete p;` doesn't affect `p`. It destroys the object that `p` points to and frees its memory. `p` still has the value that it had before.